# How to return task status from a mail item?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a code that returns various properties for mail items. I'm trying to add the "task status" to my report.

I get a run-time error '438' "Object doesn't support this property or method". I'm trying to extract whether the little flag in Outlook is completed (aka checked).

Here is what I have so far:

```
        For Each currentTask In currentItem.Tasks
            Debug.Print currentTask.Status
            Report = Report & currentTask.Status
        Next
```

It is part of this larger sub:

```
Private Sub GetAllEmailsInFolder(CurrentFolder As Outlook.Folder, Report As String)
    Dim currentItem
    Dim attachment As attachment
    Dim currentMail As MailItem
    Dim currenTask As TaskItem

    Report = Report & "Folder Name: " & CurrentFolder.Name & " (Store: " & CurrentFolder.Store.DisplayName & ")" & " (Date of report: " _
        & Date & ")" & vbCrLf & "Subject Name|Categories|Attachment Count|Task Status|Attachment Name(s)" & vbCrLf
    For Each currentItem In CurrentFolder.Items
        Report = Report & currentItem.Subject & "|"
        Report = Report & currentItem.Categories & "|"
        Report = Report & currentItem.Attachments.Count & "|"
        'need help here
        For Each currentTask In currentItem.Tasks
            Debug.Print currentTask.Status
            Report = Report & currentTask.Status
        Next
        '
        For Each attachment In currentItem.Attachments
            Debug.Print attachment.FileName
            Report = Report & attachment.FileName & ","
        Next

        Report = Report & vbCrLf
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the exact problem - are you getting an error? If Yes, what error?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320330.aspx  A mail item doesn't have a `Tasks` property

Comment: @TimWilliams hi Tim, thank you for the reference. I do get a run-time error '438' "Object doesn't support this property or method.

What i'm trying to extract is where the little flag in outlook is completed (aka checked) or not. Perhaps you know a better way of pulling this?

Comment: A mailitem has a boolean `IsMarkedAsTask` (as far as I can tel there's only one associated task) property.  If you want to know if it's completed then check the `TaskCompletedDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mailitem has a `.FlagStatus` property.

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Private Sub GetAllEmailsInFolder(CurrentFolder As outlook.Folder, Report As String)

    ' Code for flags not reliable in IMAP accounts
    
    Dim currentItem As Object
    Dim attachment As attachment
    Dim currentMail As MailItem

    'Dim currenTask As TaskItem   ' <--- missing Option Explicit?
    Dim currentTask As TaskItem
    
    Dim currentFolderItems As Items
    
    Report = Report & "Folder Name: " & CurrentFolder.Name & " (Store: " & CurrentFolder.Store.DisplayName & ")" & " (Date of report: " _
        & Date & ")" & vbCrLf & "Subject Name|Categories|Attachment Count|Task Status|Attachment Name(s)" & vbCrLf
    
    Set currentFolderItems = CurrentFolder.Items
    
    For Each currentItem In currentFolderItems
        
        If currentItem.Class = olMail Then
        
            Set currentMail = currentItem
            
            With currentMail
            
                Debug.Print .Subject
                
                Report = Report & .Subject & "|"
                Report = Report & .categories & "|"
                Report = Report & .Attachments.Count & "|"
                
                ' No longer in current documentation
                ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/bb644164(v=office.14)
                ' Still could be good for decades
                '   0 - olNoFlag
                '   1 - olFlagComplete
                '   2 - olFlagMarked
                Debug.Print ".FlagStatus.: " & .FlagStatus
                
                'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.flagrequest
                Debug.Print ".FlagRequest: " & .FlagRequest
                
                Report = Report & .FlagStatus
                
                For Each attachment In .Attachments
                    Debug.Print attachment.Filename
                    Report = Report & attachment.Filename & ","
                Next
                
            End With
            
            Report = Report & vbCrLf
            Debug.Print Report
            
        ElseIf currentItem.Class = olTask Then
        
            Set currentTask = currentItem
            
            With currentTask
            
                Report = Report & .Subject & "|"
                Report = Report & .categories & "|"
                Report = Report & .Attachments.Count & "|"
                
                Debug.Print ".Status.....: " & .Status

                Report = Report & .Status
                
                For Each attachment In .Attachments
                    Debug.Print attachment.Filename
                    Report = Report & attachment.Filename & ","
                Next
                
            End With
            
            Report = Report & vbCrLf
            Debug.Print Report
        
        Else
            Debug.Print "neither a mailitem nor a taskitem"
            
        End If
        
        Set currentItem = Nothing
        Set currentTask = Nothing
        Set currentMail = Nothing

    Next

End Sub


Private Sub test()

    Dim currFolder As Folder
    Dim reportStr As String
    
    Set currFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    reportStr = "FlagStaus on mailitems: "
    
    GetAllEmailsInFolder currFolder, reportStr
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MailItem.FlagDueBy / FlagIcon / FlagRequest / FlagStatus / IsMarkedAsTask / TaskCompletedDate / TaskDueDate / TaskStartDate / TaskSubject / ToDoTaskOrdinal` properties.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of a better solution, you can use the `PropertyAccessor` for this purpose.

I cannot provide you with a code snippet right now, but you have ilustrative examples on the reference page [1].

The property tag that you are looking for is `0x8025`, with DASL `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/81010003`.

You can use OutlookSpy to determine property tags of actual properties (thanks to [2] for this tip).

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor

[2] [How can I get task-specific properties from a MailItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521017/how-can-i-get-task-specific-properties-from-a-mailitem)

**Edit 1**

```
Private Function GetStatus(objItem As Object) As OlTaskStatus
    Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor

    ' MAPI-level access required to get the "status" property of a Mail Item object.
    Set oPA = objItem.PropertyAccessor
    GetStatus = oPA.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/81010003")

    Set oPA = Nothing
End Function
```